# custom directive in angular js not working

Tags: angularjs

```
App.directive('dExpandCollapse', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).click(function () {
                //var show = "false";
                $(element).find(".answer").slideToggle('200', function () {
                    // You may toggle + - icon     
                    $(element).find("span").toggleClass('faqPlus faqMinus');
                });


                if ($("div.answer:visible").length > 1) {
                    // You may toggle + - icon                      //$(this).parent().find("span.faqMinus").removeClass('faqMinus').addClass('faqPlus');
                    $(this).siblings().find(".answer").slideUp('slow');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and calling this in html as follows:

```
<div ng-app="App">
    <d-expand-collapse>
        <div><span class="faqPlus"></span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="question ui-link">Question1?</a></div>
        <div class="answer">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </d-expand-collapse>

    <d-expand-collapse>

        <div><span class="faqPlus"></span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="question ui-link">Question2 ?</a></div>
        <div class="answer">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </d-expand-collapse>

    <d-expand-collapse>
        <div>
            <span class="faqPlus"></span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="question ui-link">Question3?</a>
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </d-expand-collapse>


    <d-expand-collapse>
        <div><span class="faqPlus"></span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="question ui-link">Question 4?</a></div>
        <div class="answer">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </d-expand-collapse>


</div>
```

still its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not complete. It is not exactly clear what is not working. With some assumptions from my side I wrote this html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        angular.module('exampleApp', [])
        .directive('dExpandCollapse', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    $(element).click(function () {
                        //var show = "false";
                        $(element).find(".answer").slideToggle('200', function () {
                            // You may toggle + - icon     
                            $(element).find("span").toggleClass('faqPlus faqMinus');
                        });


                        if ($("div.answer:visible").length > 1) {
                            // You may toggle + - icon                      //$(this).parent().find("span.faqMinus").removeClass('faqMinus').addClass('faqPlus');
                            $(this).siblings().find(".answer").slideUp('slow');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        </script>
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <d-expand-collapse>
        <div><span class="faqPlus"></span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="question ui-link">Question1?</a></div>
        <div class="answer">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </d-expand-collapse>

    <d-expand-collapse>

        <div><span class="faqPlus"></span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="question ui-link">Question2 ?</a></div>
        <div class="answer">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </d-expand-collapse>

    <d-expand-collapse>
        <div>
            <span class="faqPlus"></span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="question ui-link">Question3?</a>
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </d-expand-collapse>


    <d-expand-collapse>
        <div><span class="faqPlus"></span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="question ui-link">Question 4?</a></div>
        <div class="answer">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </d-expand-collapse>
    </body>
</html>
```

It delivered almost an accordion. Please provide more details about what is the exact problem you are facing.